# Is the number of nodes in an ORBDD 2n + 2?

Tags: combinatorics, bdd

Wikipedia says that the number of nodes in a ORBDD (Order Reduced Binary Decision Diagrams) of order $x_1 < x_2 < \dots < x_{2n}$ is $2n + 2$.

But I can't find proof. Anyone?

Comment: A BDD with order x1 < x2 < x3 < x4 and function f = (x1 v x2) Ʌ (x3 v x4) has 4 nodes, one each for the variables and two terminating nodes 0 and 1. 
So, for function with (x1, x2, ….., x2m) will always have 2m nodes, one each for the variables. In addition there will be terminating nodes 0 and 1. Hence, the number of nodes will always be 2m + 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't say that. To [quote](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_decision_diagram#Variable_ordering):

> Let us consider the Boolean function $f(x_1,\ldots, x_{2n}) = x_1x_2 + x_3x_4 + \cdots + x_{2n-1}x_{2n}$. Using the variable ordering $x_1 < x_3 < \cdots < x_{2n-1} < x_2 < x_4 < \cdots < x_{2n}$, the BDD needs $2^{n+1}$ nodes to represent the function. Using the ordering $x_1 < x_2 < x_3 < x_4 < \cdots < x_{2n-1} < x_{2n}$, the BDD consists of $2n + 2$ nodes.

It is only talking about that particular function, and demonstrating the difference that different variable orderings can make.

As it says a few lines later:

> There are functions for which the graph size is always exponential — independent of variable ordering.

Bryant [1] proves several functions have exponentially sized OBDDs, regardless of the variable ordering (see for example Theorems 2 and 4 in the paper).

**References**

1. Randal E. Bryant, ["On the Complexity of VLSI Implementations and Graph Representations of Boolean Functions with Application to Integer Multiplication"](http://repository.cmu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1191&context=compsci), IEEE Trans. on Computers, 40(2):205-226, 1991.

Comment: Proof anywhere?

Comment: @kaitlynrutledge I've added a reference to a paper with a couple of proofs. They're too long and complicated to reproduce here (it would require reproducing a large chunk of the paper).